# Returning a value from R function

Tags: r, function, return

I have the following R function

```
pa <- function(data){

   if (unique(data$bundles_product_id) == 'B0000DJX70'){
    print ('B0000DJX70')
    return(NA)
  }
   # ... some code
```

}
data looks like this:

```
1   422 B0000DJX70  14  B00020LXYA  32.33071    55.93000
2   423 B0000DJX70  15  B00020LXYA  32.10714    53.74429
3   424 B0000DJX70  16  B00020LXYA  30.45429    53.08143
4   425 B0000DJX70  17  B00020LXYA  31.82214    50.21000
5   426 B0000DJX70  18  B00020LXYA  33.01727    49.98429
6   427 B0000DJX70  19  B00020LXYA  36.51714    50.07857
7   428 B0000DJX70  20  B00020LXYA  36.22286    37.67000
8   429 B0000DJX70  21  B00020LXYA  36.31714    37.67000
9   430 B0000DJX70  22  B00020LXYA  36.39286    38.14286
```

Then, when the interpreter gets to the if block and get inside it, it fails returning NA with the following strange error:

```
Error in if (xor(((max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) < (mean(x,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

while the warnings are:

```
Warning messages:
1: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I'm clueless, since this function is called in a loop and works fine many times, only with this specific data set it fails.
Any help appreciated in advance

addition:

```
Browse[2]> dput(unique(data$bundles_product_id))
"B0000DJX70"
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `unique(data$bundles_product_id) == 'B0000DJX70'` returns a vector and `if` isn't vectorized. May be wrap it up into `any` or something, though its not very clear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Judging by the messages you are getting, the problem isn't exclusively in the `if` statement provided.

Comment: David - I added something regarding yout remark, it seems like unique(data$bundles_product_id) does not return a vector

Comment: Like Pierre said, it seems that the error is in some other `if` statement, with the `# ... some code` phase

Comment: Although the if block is the first block in the function I could accept what you guys are saying. What I don't understand is why the code throws the error only on the return statement

Comment: We can't really debug it without seeing the missing part and a data set that reproduces this error. Other than that, SO isn't really meant to be a debugging site.

Answer (score 0):

To me the behavior is as expected:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "1   422 B0000DJX70  14  B00020LXYA  32.33071    55.93000
2   423 B0000DJX70  15  B00020LXYA  32.10714    53.74429
3   424 B0000DJX70  16  B00020LXYA  30.45429    53.08143
4   425 B0000DJX70  17  B00020LXYA  31.82214    50.21000
5   426 B0000DJX70  18  B00020LXYA  33.01727    49.98429
6   427 B0000DJX70  19  B00020LXYA  36.51714    50.07857
7   428 B0000DJX70  20  B00020LXYA  36.22286    37.67000
8   429 B0000DJX70  21  B00020LXYA  36.31714    37.67000
9   430 B0000DJX70  22  B00020LXYA  36.39286    38.14286", header=F,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

pa <- function(data){

  if (unique(data$V3) == 'B0000DJX70'){
    print ('B0000DJX70')
    return(NA) #invisible() would be better
  }}
pa(dat)
[1] "B0000DJX70"
[1] NA
```